# How to Make show Save As Dialog box in asp.net web Application using Button click

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have worked in Web Application exporting datas in grid and I want to Save them Using Save as dialog box either in C#,Javascript.

```
function openDialog() {

        var input = $(document.createElement('input'));
        input.attr("type", "file")
        input.trigger('click');
        return false;
    }
```

test

Comment: If you want to show the save as popup, you will have to push the file from server. Files generated in browser don't give this popup. Now in your action method, just return a file. When someone will browse that method, he will get the popup.

Answer (score 0):

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(string fileHash)
    {
        //read file 
        byte[] fileData = await _deviceFileApiService.GetFileData(fileHash);

        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new ByteArrayContent(fileData)
        };
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = fileResource.FileName
        };

        return response;
    }
```

on UI

```
<a href="<you url to action here>/get">save as</a>
```

When user click on link, save as dialog will be appeared.